# Chartkick - Customizing a graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using `chartkick` gem to plot a graph. I have been able to successfully plot the graph. However, I am unhappy with the chart data presentation and want to know if we can edit is somehow so that chart can be understood more easily.

Below is what I am exactly trying to do.

- I am trying to build an application using `Ruby on Rails 7` to calculate process operational excellence.
- Per operations management, every process has something called as Design Time. The design time is nothing but the difference between upper limit and lower limit. Design time divided by 2 is called as Target value.
- I have been able to plot the upper limit and lower limit in a bar type graph using the `chartick` gem and then I am also able to plot Target value on the graph.

Now this is all-right, but I think the way the data is getting presented is not easy to understand. A user will have to read this graph very carefully to understand.

Here is how he graph is looking at present:

[image]

I want that the Target value (shown in yellow color) if represented as below will be easier to understand.

[image]

Is it possible to **NOT** to plot a value with respect to 0 ?